# SERIOUS help port forwarding on my router?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, router, portforwarding, ubuntu-server

Okay, so I know that these kind of questions are pretty popular on SO, but please hear me out. I have a belkin router, model F9K1102 v1. I also have a Westell Dual Connection modem, model A90-220015-04. Now, I have done port forwarding before, although it was with the same modem and a different (Cisco) router. My modem is IP 192.168.0.47 and my router is 192.168.2.1. I followed the following tutorial to set up port forwarding on the Belkin router:

http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Belkin/F9K1102v1/Apache.htm

And set up the following under "Virtual Servers":

[image]

Yet, whenever I try accessing my public IP (from whatsmyip.org) via my iPhone on 4G, it can't find the server. The connection times out. Online port sniffers say that port 80 isn't open. This is becoming very frustrating and I really need it to work. Verizon is my ISP and I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04, btw.

Any help towards resolving this would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You might find better answers if you post it at http://serverfault.com/ instead.

Comment: This question doesn't belong on stackoverflow, please migrate it.

Comment: @Xilexio, I was not aware this site existed. I have migrated my question to there. I just posted in SO because I didn't know where else I could seek help. Thanks.

Comment: @Xilexio I think you mean [su].

Comment: @Michael Hampton: I meant serverfault, but IMO either would be good. This is kind of meta, but why do you think superuser is better?

Comment: @Xilexio Because it's off topic at SF.

Answer (score 1):

Before you start your port forwading and stuff. Ask your provider (Verizon) if you have public or static ip on their server. Basically when you see your extrernal ip . This ip might be your provider's ip , not fully yours. So, when packets are sent to the server from your home, servers responds to you and sends packets BACK, but it sends them to a general Verizon server,and then Verizon sends those packets back to your ip. The point is that only Verizon server can fully access your ip. But if you want full access from outside , ask Verizon.

Answer (score 0):

Check your external/WAN/public IPv4 address. If it is in the ranges `100.64.x.x-100.127.x.x`, `10.x.x.x`, `172.16.x.x-172.31.x.x` or `192.168.x.x` then you don't actually have a public IPv4 address and you cannot do port forwarding. And even if it is in another range: compare it with what you see at whatsmyip.org. If it is different then you won't be able to do port forwarding.